# Querydsl - how to use MathExpressions min expression

Tags: querydsl

Each time I try to use `MathExpressions.min` it results with `NullPointerException`, e.g.:

```
MathExpressions.min(Expressions.constant(1), a.sqrt())
MathExpressions.min(Expressions.constant(1), Expressions.constant(2))
```

I can't find in documentation any usage of `MathExpressions.min`. Does anybody have experience with min function and know how to use it?

Comment: Is a null? Where did this MathExpressions library come from?

Comment: It comes from com.querydsl.core.types.dsl

Comment: Here's some documentation: http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/4.0.3/apidocs/com/querydsl/core/types/dsl/MathExpressions.html

Comment: I'm going to guess your issue is caused by `a` being null. if it is isn't we will likely need an minimal reproducible example.